# Excel VBA Open xlsx File From Folder Without writing Path

Tags: vba, excel

I want to open Excel xlsx file without writing path by using variables. I din't know why but it is not working. I have a folder with the main workbook and another one that I want to open that is xlsx. I want to name it UnionWB.

```
  Private Sub cmdStartMonth_Click()
    'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Analyze month by selecting
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim UnionWB As Workbook
    Dim MonthName As String
    MonthName = ListMonth.Value
    myExtension = "*.xlsx*"
    Set UnionWB = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & myExtension)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

> Set UnionWB = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & myExtension)

Comment: Where is the file on your computer? What is wrong with declaring the folderpath, should it be dynamic?

Comment: I want it to be dynamic. and the folder names are not in english, I cant use in the code. @Luuklag

Comment: @Luuklag did you understood what I mean afetr the edit?

Comment: Your code is saying the file name is `*.xlsx` and not a specific file name.  `myExtension` isn't declared and `ThisWorkbook.Path` won't have a file separator on the the end - it should be `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myExtension`.  You'll still need to sort out which file it's trying to open though - `*.xlsx` doesn't refer to a single file.  `MonthName` isn't used anywhere and `ScreenUpdating` & `EnableEvents` isn't needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "_without writing path_".  `ThisWorkbook.Path` is a pretty static path - it's wherever the workbook containing the code is saved, so the workbook you're trying to open must be in the same folder as the original file.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - yes that is excatly what i am trying to do, can you fix my code?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  I've pointed out what I can see is wrong with your code but I don't know what you're trying to do.  I don't know what "_without writing path by using variables_" means in this context.  Where does the month name come into it?  Is it a single file or all files you want opened (you're using `*` which I take to mean a number of files with some kind of wildcard name).

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook i am trying to open one file that is xlsx type - to name it and to take data out of there. the file is in the same folder as the main file.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook the file i am trying to open is the only xlsx file inside the folder.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook the month is not relavant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple of examples that may help.

The first will ask you to select the correct file and then open it:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim sWrkbkPath As String
    Dim UnionWB As Workbook

    sWrkbkPath = GetFile(ThisWorkbook.Path)
    If sWrkbkPath <> "" Then
        Set UnionWB = Workbooks.Open(sWrkbkPath)
        MsgBox UnionWB.Name
    End If

End Sub

Function GetFile(Optional startFolder As Variant = -1) As Variant
    Dim fle As FileDialog
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Set fle = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fle
        .Title = "Select your Union Workbook"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "My Union Workbook", "*.xlsx", 1
        If startFolder = -1 Then
            .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        Else
            If Right(startFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                .InitialFileName = startFolder & "\"
            Else
                .InitialFileName = startFolder
            End If
        End If
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        vItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFile = vItem
    Set fle = Nothing
End Function
```

The second method assumes you only have a single xlsx file in the same folder as ThisWorkbook and opens the first file it finds:

```
Public Sub OpenOnlyXLSXInFolder()
    Dim sWrkbkPath As String
    Dim UnionWB As Workbook
    sWrkbkPath = Dir$(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.xlsx")

    'Only expecting a single file so no need to loop.
    If sWrkbkPath <> "" Then
        Set UnionWB = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sWrkbkPath)
        MsgBox UnionWB.Name
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: the second sub is what I need, but somehow it says that it could not find the file with its right name and it is the only xlsx file in the folder

Comment: "sorry we couldn't find "bla bla". is it possible it was removed, renamed or deleted?"

Comment: these 2 files are the only one in the folder and still it shows me a massage box that it cant find the xlsx file in the folder.

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. For some reason it was working for me even though `Dir` only returns the workbook name and not the path as well.  When I tried it in a different folder I had the same error as you - I've updated the code to include the path when opening the file.